# Is there a way to overlay two DensityPlot3D graphs

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

I'm trying plot 3D wave functions around potentials.  I'd like to show the potential function on a `DensityPlot3D`, and the resulting wave functions on the same graph.  It would seem that something like `Show` should be able to do this, but apparently this isn't so.  Is there any way to do this?

The wave function is the solution to:

```
   \[Psi] = u /. 
    First@NDSolve[{I D[u[t, x, y, z], t] == -D[u[t, x, y, z], {x, 2}] -
     D[u[t, x, y, z], {y, 2}] - D[u[t, x, y, z], {z, 2}] +
    (-.5 + 
       100 Sin[Pi 3. x/5]^8 Sin[Pi 3. y/5]^8 Sin[Pi 3. z/5]^8) u[
      t, x, y, z],
  
  u[0., x, y, z] == Exp[-((x - 1)^2. + (y)^2. + (z)^2.)], 
  u[t, -5., y, z] == u[t, 5., y, z], 
  u[t, x, -5., z] == u[t, x, 5., z], 
  u[t, x, y, -5.] == u[t, x, y, 5.]}, 
 u, {t, 0., 5.}, {x, -5., 5.}, {y, -5., 5.}, {z, -5., 5.}, 
 Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
   "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
     "DifferenceOrder" -> "Pseudospectral"}}];
```

The potential function that I'd like to overlay with, perhaps different colors, is

```
   (-.5 + 100 Sin[Pi 3. x/5]^8 Sin[Pi 3. y/5]^8 Sin[Pi 3. z/5]^8)
```

If this were possible with something like Show, I'd be able to rotate the overlay and see the evolving 3D wave function from different directions.

Ultimately the goal is to make a table of DensityPlot3D's of the modulus (Psi*Psi) of the function Psi and the overlayed potential function so I can Animate the time evolution of the modulus of Psi against the background of the potential.

As things stand now, I don't seem to be able to make a graph with both the potential and the modulus of the wave function visible.  I've tried to fudge this by adding the modulus to the potential, and graphing that.  This works to a degree since the wave function is typically small in the region of high potential, but there is little flexibility for coloring the potential and the modulus of the wave function differently....

Comment: Can you provide examples of both plots?

Answer (score 2):

```
aa = SliceDensityPlot3D[
   -1 + Sin[-(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)], 
   {"ZStackedPlanes", 1},
  {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, 0, 3}];

bb = Plot3D[2.5 + .3 Sin[x^2 - y^3], 
  {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
  PlotPoints -> 100,
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5],
  PlotRange -> {0, 3}];

Show[aa,bb]
```

[image]